# how to run the script without blocking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

IE9 is blocking my script. Is there anyway to run the script without blocking it?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking" here?

Comment: Are you asking about "loading" (as in the question title) or "running" (as in the question text)? And given that you mention IE9 explicitly, are you saying other browsers and other versions of IE behave the way you want?

Comment: IE9 is not allowing my script. when I run the script it asks confirmation as "allow blocked content..." I am facing this only in IE9

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automaticaly allow blocked content in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038724/how-to-automaticaly-allow-blocked-content-in-ie)

Comment: You are loading the files from server with http://www or from your hard drive?

Comment: Do you mean action script is blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change security settings for your own browser but you cannot control user's browser behavior for blocking scripts.