# Internet Explorer Cache-Query. How to prevent IE to ask for blocked Content?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, caching

I am creating a website and load the text from the data: text.txt. My problem was at first, that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin didnt worked. I fixed it and became the problem that in IE the load of .txt didnt worked cause of caching. I fixed it with the Meta-Tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

My Problem is, that while the page loads he asks me: Content from this website was blocked.

If i say yes, he loads the documents, if i say no, it fails.

Can i prevent IE not to ask me that and just acept loading the files?

Thx for help

German:

Hallo, ich habe meine Website so programmiert, dass ich Texte auf Englisch oder Deutsch in eine HTML Seite lade und anzeige. Mein Problem ist nun, das der Internet Explorer das gecached hat und er somit die Seiten nicht geladen hat. Dann habe ich die meta Tags hinzugefügt, dass er nicht cached. Jetzt meldet der IE jedes mal beim Öffnen der Seite:

Das ausführen von Skripts wurde für diese Seite eingeschränkt. Wenn ich nun sage, geblockte Inhalte anzeigen, macht er es, aber wenn ich nichts drücke, lädt er die Textdateien nicht mehr. Wie kann ich die IE-Meldung unterdrücken und ohne Abfrage die Dokumente laden?

Comment: The better approach would be to ask why you're loading information from a text file, and if there is no better alternative, how are you doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One question similar to this is answered in SO suggests adding a line like
 `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` above the tag which is used to load the .txt file.Please refer this:[How to automatically allow blocked content in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038724/how-to-automaticaly-allow-blocked-content-in-ie)