# After MOTW comment, links <a> on the page stopped working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, anchor, activex, mark-of-the-web

I was facing problem of 'Active-X controls' while running pages in Internet Explorer.

```
<!-- internet explorer restricted this webpage from running activex controls -->
```

I found the solution mentioned by Ray-cheng in this post

```
(having <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet --> )
```

[How to automatically allow blocked content in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038724/how-to-automatically-allow-blocked-content-in-ie?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

After adding this line, links on my page stopped working.

i.e.
    `a href='Images/abc.png'> Image`

Pls suggest how can I make it work ?

Thanks in advance.