# Javascript not executing using XAMPP

Tags: javascript, xampp

In my html document (which is in the `xampp/htdocs` directory), I'm using an external .js file. The .js file is in the same directory as my html file. I'm simply trying to use `document.write()` function and it's not printing anything.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Whats the issue?

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include 'include/head_elements.html'?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Company Account creation</h1>
        <div id="registration_menu">
            <!--Elements are added and removed dynamically using JS-->
        </div>
        <script>
            hello();
            load_element_group("email_verification");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS file

```
function hello(){
    document.write("Hello world")
}
```

Comment: you made a function, but you're not running it.

Comment: @StevenStark I added a script tag in the body section and called it

Comment: Works fine for me. I see the `<h1>`, and below it says "Hello World". 1. check your browser console for error messages 2. press Ctrl+U to look at the source HTML and click the underlined script src _register.js_. Do you see the script?

Comment: It only shows the `<h1>` for me

Comment: Are you getting any error, or just no output?

Comment: @Amessihel Still doesnt work. Tried opening the document not using `localhost` (just opening like a regular file) and same thing

Comment: @AnisR. No output

Comment: Did you see what I added to my previous comment? The most likely reason is that the script isn't loaded. Windows has an option to hide known extensions, so you should double check that your script is called `register.js` and not `Register.js` or `register.js.js`.

Comment: @ChrisG it is `register.js`. @Amessihel : The browser console says `hello is not defined`

Comment: @Amessihel Opening it locally works fine (after renaming `index.php` to `index.html`).

Comment: Did you do what I suggested and test the `src` in the HTML source view?

Comment: Just a thought, but some security policies prevent running scripts in IE.  @AndrewKor you using IE? https://i.imgur.com/DXwAaC2.png

Comment: @AndrewKor - apologies, I didn't notice that tbh. I have added an answer here to make up for my mistake ;)

Comment: @tresf it ended up being a security issue of some kind.. i was using chrome. works fine now. thanks for all your help

Comment: @AndrewKor Ok, I'll provide it in answer form.

Comment: It works fine on IE (if you open it via localhost/). What security issue exactly? How did you fix this?

Comment: Added screenshot to answer.  Simply setting `Local Intranet` to High will cause this.

Comment: @AndrewKor Can you help demystify some questions on the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer's security policy may block certain scripts from running on a local machine.

[image]

There are ways to avoid this -- such as by adding the XAMPP website as a trusted location -- but often this gets tricky since the default "Intranet Zone" is auto-configured on a PC and modifying that can have other consequences (different zones assume different settings, such as passing NTLM credentials to local websites).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7038775/3196753

A quick fix often is to add the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) to the URL, but depending on the zone settings, this may still cause issues.

A final solution, and one many developers fall back on, is to actually use a registered DNS address, such as http://localtest.me/, which points back to localhost and should use the "Internet Zone".

As [`Chris G`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/) points out in the comments, this isn't typical.  Normally `localhost` can be used without issue so I've provided an example `Local Intranet` setting which can cause this:
[image]

Comment: Or just use `localhost`, which works for me in IE just fine (and Chrome). Your screenshot shows you have opened the file locally, in that case IE will indeed present a warning. This is about XAMPP though, which means there's a PHP based web server to avoid exactly those kind of problems already in place (and OP is using it, too, according to a previous comment).

Comment: Example security settings added to answer.

Comment: Sorry, but for me, even with all security set to "High", opening the page via `localhost` on IE11 works fine. No warning. "Hello World" is displayed. Plus, OP is using Chrome.

Comment: Interesting.  `Hello world` disappears in my local when using "High".  The Internet zone has its own auto-detection logic (influenced by three check boxes), and worse there are silent security changes that differ between domain and non-domain PCs.  Regardless of these differences, Chrome should never (well, rarely -- it can prevent SSO, but never seen it break a JS include) be affected.  I'm not at all offended if you downvote this answer, I assumed IE was the culprit.

Comment: You're right; I had `localhost` in "Trusted Sites". Still, OP was using Chrome, so the problem was something else. I can reproduce OP's issue if I manually block JavaScript for `localhost` in Chrome's settings, but OP said he got `hello is not defined`. My money is on a typo.

Comment: If "security" was deemed the culprit and it wasn't IE related, my next guess would be local file permissions.