# Javascript not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

For some reason, my function isn't firing in IE. It works in everything else, Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge. Can anyone see a specific issue with this? I think I've narrowed it down to this specific function. All other js seems to be working just fine. Thanks!

Uses Windows Server 2012 R2

this is the function in question:

```
function mySearch() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('connect-cat');


  for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

  if (nodes[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
      nodes[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      nodes[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

A bit of HTML used in the page, probably not necessary to diagnose this problem but trying to give as much as I can.

The search bar:

```
<div style="width:100%;margin-left:320px;">
      <input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="javascript:searching();" Placeholder="Please enter a search term...">&nbsp;</input>
      <input id="lawsonbox" type="checkbox" onchange="javascript:storefront();" style="position:absolute;width:15px;" ><font size="-3" style="margin-left:22px;">Highlight customizable Storefront products</font></input>
  </div>
<br/><br/>
```

A couple of searchable products, html:

```
<div class="connect-cat" style="width:237px;height:350px;position:inherit;float:left;visibility: visible; display: block;">
<a href="CreateUserDocument.aspx?code=ADBUILDER8">
<img style="width:217px;" src="Custom/Themes/standard/Inserts/images/Ad_Print_Thumb.jpg"/>
<br/>
<div id="ptitle">
Ad - Print
<br/>
Customize on Storefront
</div>
<div id="pdesc">
Bring awareness and education
<br/>
to your audience.
</div>
</a>
<div style="display:none;">"print ad"ad print"experience more"experience more campaign"first choice campaign"home health collection"assisted living collection" post-acute rehabilitation services collection"ad"</div>
</div>

<div class="connect-cat" style="width:237px;height:350px;position:inherit;float:left;visibility: visible; display: block;">
<a href="Custom/Themes/standard/Inserts/Forms/1_1_15_Radio_TV sheet.xls">
<img class="sfclass" style="width:217px;" src="Custom/Themes/standard/Inserts/images/Ad_Radio_Thumb.jpg"/>
<br/>
<div id="ptitle">
Ad - Radio
<br/>
Download
</div>
<div id="pdesc">
Work with local station to produce.
<br/>
Must use Society-approved music bed.
</div>
</a>
<div style="display:none;">"radio ad"ad radio"experience more"experience more campaign"first choice campaign"ad"lawson"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `onkeyup="javascript:searching();"` shouldn't that be `onkeyup="mySearch();"` ?

Comment: Check the compatibility table for [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (It's not supported by IE)

Comment: Also, you don't need `javascript:` in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed in place of URLs, like in `href`.

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried the debugger and all it says is mySearch is not defined. I tried the debugger but that got me nowhere.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'll look into this as I'm guessing this is probably the issue.

Comment: There weren't any errors when the function was loading? Those errors would explain why the function isn't defined.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837969/javascript-not-executing-using-xampp/55838066?noredirect=1#comment98340512_55838066) He was also having trouble loading a .js file in IE, it was due to a security setting.

Comment: @Barmar Looking back, I had to move past the first error. Apologies, I don't work in I.E. ever.

I get the following two errors: 

Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference - Line: 1342, Column: 3

Object doesn't support property or method 'includes' - Line: 1348, Column: 3

The funciton begins on line 1340.

Comment: The first error means that `document.getElementById("Search");` isn't finding the element for some reason. The second error is what Sterling Archer told you about.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element for the first error.

Answer (score 0):

First, modify the function name, make sure you are using the defined function.

Second, with refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), we know that the includes() method not support IE browser, so, try to use the [indexof method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check whether the innerhtml contains the filter value.

Try to modify your code as below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function searching() {
            var input = document.getElementById("Search");
            var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
            var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('connect-cat');


            for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

                if (nodes[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) {
                    nodes[i].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    nodes[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
        function storefront() {

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%;margin-left:320px;">
        <input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="javascript:searching();" Placeholder="Please enter a search term...">&nbsp;</input>
        <input id="lawsonbox" type="checkbox" onchange="javascript:storefront();" style="position:absolute;width:15px;"><font size="-3" style="margin-left:22px;">Highlight customizable Storefront products</font></input>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="connect-cat" style="width:237px;height:350px;position:inherit;float:left;visibility: visible; display: block;">
        <a href="CreateUserDocument.aspx?code=ADBUILDER8">
            <img style="width:217px;" src="Custom/Themes/standard/Inserts/images/Ad_Print_Thumb.jpg" />
            <br />
            <div id="ptitle">
                Ad - Print
                <br />
                Customize on Storefront
            </div>
            <div id="pdesc">
                Bring awareness and education
                <br />
                to your audience.
            </div>
        </a>
        <div style="display:none;">"print ad"ad print"experience more"experience more campaign"first choice campaign"home health collection"assisted living collection" post-acute rehabilitation services collection"ad"</div>
    </div>

    <div class="connect-cat" style="width:237px;height:350px;position:inherit;float:left;visibility: visible; display: block;">
        <a href="Custom/Themes/standard/Inserts/Forms/1_1_15_Radio_TV sheet.xls">
            <img class="sfclass" style="width:217px;" src="Custom/Themes/standard/Inserts/images/Ad_Radio_Thumb.jpg" />
            <br />
            <div id="ptitle">
                Ad - Radio
                <br />
                Download
            </div>
            <div id="pdesc">
                Work with local station to produce.
                <br />
                Must use Society-approved music bed.
            </div>
        </a>
        <div style="display:none;">"radio ad"ad radio"experience more"experience more campaign"first choice campaign"ad"lawson"</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Simply using "indexOf" worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip. Not sure why I didn't think of using that.